# Como pivotar uma base com valores diferentes nas variaveis?

Tags: r

Tenho uma base com a seguinte estrutura:

| D1 | D2 | D3 | V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D35 | D36 | D37 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| D37 | D40 | D45 | 1 | 3 | 2 |

Preciso se uma forma de deixar para valor nas variaveis D1, D2 e D3, como uma variavel, e levar para essa nova varivavel D os valores que estão em V1, V2 ou V3 referente a esse D. Ficando o dataset, esse forma:

| D1 | D2 | D3 | V1 | V2 | V3 | D35 | D36 | D37 | D40 | D45 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D35 | D36 | D37 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | NA | NA |
| D37 | D40 | D45 | 1 | 3 | 2 | NA | NA | 1 | 3 | 2 |

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Porque é que a coluna final `D37` tem 2 em vez de 4 (em cima)?

Comment: Oi Rui, foi um erro de digitação. Fiz a correção do texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é um bocado complicada e talvez haja mais simples mas o código abaixo funciona.

```r
x <- 'D1    D2  D3  V1  V2  V3
D35     D36     D37     1   3   4
D37     D40     D45     1   3   2'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

bind_cols(
  df1 %>%
    select(-starts_with("V")) %>%
    mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_to = "D", values_to = "DV"),
  df1 %>%
    select(-starts_with("D")) %>%
    mutate(id2 = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -id2)
) %>%
  select(-D, -id2, -name) %>%
  complete(id, DV, fill = list(value = NA)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = DV, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .)
#>    D1  D2  D3 V1 V2 V3 D35 D36 D37 D40 D45
#> 1 D35 D36 D37  1  3  4   1   3   4  NA  NA
#> 2 D37 D40 D45  1  3  2  NA  NA   1   3   2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>